# JQuery: I get an error I cannot define

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do this:

```
var rows = $('#_table>tbody>tr').show();
rows.find('td:nth-child(1):not(:contains("'+typed_val+'"))').parent().hide();
```

It works.

However,

When I do this:

```
col_pos=1
var rows = $('#_table>tbody>tr').show();
rows.find('td:nth-child('+col_pos+'):not(:contains("'+typed_val+'"))').parent().hide();
```

It does not work.

Some reasons why this may be happening?

Comment: Please define "does not work."

Comment: Does using this, `var col_pos=1;` make any difference?

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qmsah/

Comment: -1, not much information given. And its really not an strange error at all. If you really knew JavaScript, then you would know how to define a variable.

Comment: @Shawn31313, I have been learning javascript from yesterday, so you are right. And on the information, I did summarize things too much, I thought the code would speak for itself. Noted.

Comment: Oh, ok. Yea it did, but giving lots of information will make it easier for everyone even though your right, the code speaks for itself.

Comment: Also, wow, did you have any experience in any other coding. For a starter the code is fine.

Comment: Yes, I guess SOF beginner mistakes. By the way, this is what I have been doing: https://github.com/kfk/Javascript_Learning/blob/master/tutorial02.html. There is no plugin in jquery that both filter rows on text and numbers, so I have to do it... I know python and learning clojure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code snippets are almost equal. The problem in this case can be caused by not delcaring a variable prior using it in strict mode. Prefix your variable by `var`:

```
var col_pos=1;
var rows = $('#_table>tbody>tr').show();
```

If the error is indeed caused by not having declared the variable in strict mode, the error would be:

> `assignment to undeclared variable col_pos`
>
> ---
>
> Bonus: You should replace `.find()` by `.children()`, since you don't want to possibly select cells in child tables.